# ANSI in BitchX not displaying properly

Tags: gnu-screen, ansi

I am attempting to get ANSI to display properly in a screen session using Iterm2 on OS X, the default TERM is set to

```
screen.xterm-256color
```

I tried

```
export TERM=vt100
```

and

```
export TERM=ansi
```

[image]

[image]

and

```
export TERM=xterm 
w/ tmux
```

[image]

Comment: I also use BitchX with similar issue on special characters only  my setup is TERM=xterm & using tmux instead of screen :)

Comment: ya, I just tried xterm, same thing though, maybe im setting it wrong?

Comment: Is this question about bitchx colors or is it about terminal colors? The two are totally different. I write a tool that does this kind of thing, and IRC clients use different color syntax than terminals do. You also can only safely use a subset of the colors to be cross platform consistent, but it's unclear from your question what you are actually trying to do. Your first image clearly is being sent color syntax that the machine doesn't understand, or the application, or the terminal. I use only I think 12 colors that are known fairly safe re background/foreground color combos.

Comment: On the bright side, your purplish image is quite nice, and would make a fine work of computer type art. I doubt it can be improved much aesthetically on that side of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't the terminal emulation - leave the TERM setting as is.

It's that the character set used by those part of the UI is CP437, but your terminal is set to another character set (probably UTF8).

You can either set iTerm2 to use CP437 if it supports that (the setting is under Terminal / Character Encoding), or you can use the [cp437 utility](https://github.com/keaston/cp437) to emulate a CP437 terminal on a UTF-8 terminal.

Answer (score 2):

setting `TERM=ansi` will not work well because `tmux` is only designed to handle the escape sequences which are found in the `screen` terminal description.

If you do `infocmp ansi screen`, you may notice these lines, showing terminal *capabilities* which terminal applications will use, that differ between the two terminal descriptions, but tmux and/or iTerm2 mishandle when misled in this manner:

```
        ech: '\E[%p1%dX', NULL.
        rep: '%p1%c\E[%p2%{1}%-%db', NULL.
        rin: '\E[%p1%dT', NULL.
        rmpch: '\E[10m', NULL. 
        rmacs: '\E[10m', '^O'.
        smacs: '\E[11m', '^N'.
        smpch: '\E[11m', NULL.
```

Since tmux is confused, there is no guarantee **what** might show up on the display.

The same applies to `TERM=xterm`.    The `tmux` manual documents this limitation.

Setting `TERM=vt100` is close (use `infocmp` to see), but most people know that [vt100's never did ANSI color](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color).